How to create a SSSSSSTetrahedron command in Mathematica?
I am trying to create coordinates of all vertices of a  tetrahedron is known by the lengths of its six edges Integer tetrahedron . I tried
SSSTriangle[51, 52, 53]


Triangle[{{0, 0}, {53, 0}, {1456/53, 2340/53}}]

ptO = {0, 0, 0};
ptA = {53, 0, 0};
ptB = {1456/53, 2340/53, 0};
ptC = {x, y, z};
{x, y, z} /. 
 Solve[{EuclideanDistance[ptO, ptC] == 80, 
   EuclideanDistance[ptA, ptC] == 84, 
   EuclideanDistance[ptB, ptC] == 117}, {x, y, z}]


{{2153/106, -(1779337/27560), -((7 Sqrt[10038791])/520)}, {2153/
106, -(1779337/27560), (7 Sqrt[10038791])/520}}

How to create a SSSSSSTetrahedron command in Mathematica to get all coordinates of vertices of the tetrahedron as SSSSSSTetrahedron[51, 52, 53, 80, 84, 117]?

I think you have got an almost complete answer already. How about packaging it like this?
Clear["Global`*"];

SSSSSSTetrahedron[s1_, s2_, s3_, s4_, s5_, s6_] := 
 Module[{ptO, ptA, ptB, ptC, cand, tri, x, y, z},
  tri = SSSTriangle[s1, s2, s3];
  {ptO, ptA, ptB} = Append[#, 0] & /@ tri[[1]];
  ptC = {x, y, z}; 
  cand = ptC /. 
    Solve[{
      EuclideanDistance[ptO, ptC] == s4, 
      EuclideanDistance[ptA, ptC] == s5, 
      EuclideanDistance[ptB, ptC] == s6}, ptC];
  (* choose one of two possible orientation *)
  ptC = SelectFirst[cand, Det[{ptA, ptB, #}] > 0 &];
  {ptO, ptA, ptB, ptC}]

tet = SSSSSSTetrahedron[51, 52, 53, 80, 84, 117]


Graphics3D[{
    {Opacity[.5], Simplex[tet]}, 
    MapThread[Text[Style[#1, 20, Bold], #2]&, {{"O", "A", "B", "C"}, tet}]}]


Appendix
In response to OP's request, I added a code which determines whether the input data is valid or not.
Clear["Global`*"];

validDataQ[{s1_, s2_, s3_, s4_, s5_, s6_}] := 
  Module[{edgelen, faces, result, triangleineq, report},
   faces = Subsets[{"A", "B", "C", "O"}, {3}];
   edgelen = {{"A", "B"} -> s1, {"B", "O"} -> s2, {"A", "O"} -> s3,
     {"C", "O"} -> s4, {"A", "C"} -> s5, {"B", "C"} -> s6};
   triangleineq[{a_, b_, c_}] := a + b > c && b + c > a && c + a > b;
   result = triangleineq[Subsets[#, {2}] /. edgelen] & /@ faces;
   If[And @@ result, Return[True]];
   report = Table[
     {StringJoin @@ tri, 
      StringJoin[#] <> "=" <> ToString[# /. edgelen] & /@ 
       Subsets[tri, {2}]}, {tri, Pick[faces, result, False]}];
   Echo[#, "Invalid triangle :"] & /@ report;
   False];

SSSSSSTetrahedron[s1_, s2_, s3_, s4_, s5_, s6_] := 
  Module[{ptO, ptA, ptB, ptC, cand, tri, x, y, z},
   If[Not[validDataQ[{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6}]], Return[{}]];
   tri = SSSTriangle[s1, s2, s3];
   {ptO, ptA, ptB} = Append[#, 0] & /@ tri[[1]];
   ptC = {x, y, z};
   cand = 
    ptC /. Solve[{EuclideanDistance[ptO, ptC] == s4, 
       EuclideanDistance[ptA, ptC] == s5, 
       EuclideanDistance[ptB, ptC] == s6}, ptC];
   (*choose one of two possible orientation*)
   ptC = SelectFirst[cand, Det[{ptA, ptB, #}] > 0 &];
   {ptO, ptA, ptB, ptC}];

Sample run:
SSSSSSTetrahedron[8, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4]


SSSSSSTetrahedron[7, 2, 10, 9, 7, 1]





I see here. It seems containing some conditions of edgs.

@minhthien_2016 You are right. For example SSSSSSTetrahedron[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] fails as it should. Do you want to include the code for checking edge lengths, so that  triangle inequalities hold for all faces?

Yes, I want the code like that.

@minhthien_2016 I edited my answer. Hopefully the code in the appendix would answer your new request.

Thank you very much.

Please consider submitting this to https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/

@IanFord Thank you for your recommendation. I'm wondering if the current form of my code is useful enough as a resource function. The order of the arguments really matters. For example, SSSSSSTetrahedron[9,6,10,10,8,2] fails but SSSSSSTetrahedron[9,6,10,10,2,8] succeeds. Are general users happy with that? One possible solution would be to provide two forms : SSSSSSTetrahedron[s1,...,s6] cares the order, but SSSSSSTetrahedron[{s1,...,s6}] does not. Any suggestion?

If you can, you can consider all cases.

@A.Kato If the version you have now can only support ordered side lengths, you could still submit it to the WFR.  You could include a disclaimer in the author or submission notes, and possibly update it in the future if you implement the version for unordered side lengths.  The design you suggest with two different syntaxes would be probably be fine for the WFR, if you decide to submit you might get more feedback from the review team.

@IanFord Thank you for your suggestion.
